# Outlook add in: Dialog centered in the task pane window

Tags: outlook-web-addins, window.open

I have an HTML page in a task pane, and I need to display an 'ok-cancel' dialog and a notification dialog:

1. If I use 'displayDialogAsync' with 'Iframe' to display the dialog within calendar event:

   Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(myUrl, { height: 100, width: 200, displayInIframe: true }, dialogCallback);

the dialog displayed fills my calendar event, 'height' & 'width' are ignored. Why is that?

2. If I need to display a dialog centered in my task pane, is it possible? How can I know the task pane position? I could use window.open(..), but I only get 'window.innerHeight' & 'window.innerWidth' to get the size of the task pane, not the position...
3. How can I display a notification dialog within the task pane to show a message and closes automatically? It should appear as a toater

Thanks,
Diego

Answer (score 1):

In the case of [Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins), the height and width values represent percentages of the height and width of the device screen. So, we suggest you retry doing that using a percentage scale.

Comment: Thanks, it solved the issue 1! Still working in a dialog with relative position (parent) and in a "toaster" within the task pane...

Comment: Can you please confirm which platform are you using for add-in?

Comment: I am using Outlook 365 Web on a Windows 10

Comment: We support all the standard functionalities. You can take care of the following features in the task pane implementation. If you are asking if we support an API for the following scenarios, we don't have that.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand which scenarios are not supported

Comment: You add-in is a web page, you can follow any HTML standard to show up content inside the task pane. [Here](https://www.javatpoint.com/html-dialog-tag#:~:text=HTML%20tag%20is%20used,user%20to%20interact%20with%20it.) is a simple example.